# cells in UITableView to new views Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview, storyboard

I create a UITableView programmatically with different cells and sections that connects to the other views in storyboard

I want to connect my cells,I mean when user select the specific row it should goes to new views "you can see in storyboard view that how they are connected to each other"

**My question is:**

**How can I connect this cells to the views I write cods for prepareForSegue:,viewDidLoad,didSelectRowAtIndexPath: and I know I should write the code for connections in cellForRowAtIndexPath: method but I don't know how should I write it ,would you please helping me**

Thanks in advance!

Here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSString *key = [[self sectionKeys] objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];
NSArray *contents = [[self sectionContents] objectForKey:key];
NSString *contentForThisRow = [contents objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

[[cell textLabel] setText:contentForThisRow];
return cell;

}



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
_selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your didSelectRowAtIndexPathMethod you should check which cell was clicked, and perform the segue:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    _selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    //maybe you could use a switch/case here, to assign the correct string to the segue identifier.
    switch (indexPath.row){
        case 0:
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"WorkTime" sender:self];
            break;
        case 1:
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Absence" sender:self];
            break;
        case 2:
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Compensation" sender:self];
            break;
    }
}
```

This way, when a cell is selected, it will perform the segue.

Comment: thanks it works but in one of my views it didn't shows one of my custom cells do you know what is the problem?

Comment: @justin If it works you should accept the answer. If a custom cell does not appear you should ask another question to address this problem :)

Comment: would you please write the switch statement since for me it didn't work

Comment: I wrote a small sample with the switch case. The number of the rows should adapt that of your table. Maybe you have to use the section instead of the row for the case. It depends on how your table is populated.

Comment: it didn't work, it wasn't the answer, since when I run the program it just bring the first view

Comment: but it just bring the workTime view when you click on Absence and Compensation